# Can we access responses of Ajax calls from Network tab of chrome driver by javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

Can we access the `responses` tab of `Network` in `Chrome Dev Tools`. I am trying to access the response of Ajax calls using selenium-python using Chrome Webdriver.

I have tried using the `performance.getEntries()` which returns only the requests made not their responses. Is there a way to access responses of ajax calls?